# How to Convert any Topographical (Pdf, deisgn on sheet, any hardcopy on paper) to shp format

Tags: gis, shapefile

Please help me in understanding: Is there a any way of converting or importing Topographical map which is a hardcopy on a paper or sheet into shp format?

Is there any tool which will help us to do so?

What are the steps involved in it?